# TextView hide word in pargephraph?

Tags: android

I'm trying to hide the words which start with '#' in a paragraph. For example:

```
String first = "This word is #12 and #word ";

TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
t.setText(first);
```

I'd like to hide words "12" and "word"..

best appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `FlyingPumba`'s answer, if you use split(" ") instead of split(' ') will work fine. There is another way of achieving it.

```
String first = "This word is #12 and #word ";

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(first, " ");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String s = st.nextToken();
    if (!s.startsWith("#")) {
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append(" ");
    }
}

TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
t.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
String first = "This word is #12 and #word ";
String[] words = first.split(" ");
String result = "";
for (String word : words) {
    if (!word.startsWith("#")) {
        result += word;
        result += " ";
    }
}

TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
t.setText(result);
```

Comment: thanks for your replay i have tried everything but it dose not work your code said : The method split(String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char)

Comment: String[] words = first.split(" ");

Comment: thanks Ruchira Randana you are right... but this code of FlyingPumba its hide only " #" not entire word, (word " #12" become "12")

Comment: @Riz that's not true, it works just fine fixing the split argument. You can see it here http://goo.gl/tud2VS

Comment: Sorry mate, you right it works perfectly. It was my mistake